# Grant LOAD from S3 with PyMySQL 1.0.2 not working

Tags: python, pymysql, amazon-aurora, ansible-module

I'm using ansible with community.mysql.mysql_user to automate database user creation on AWS aurora.  So far all the grants have been working fine, however a new requirement for "Load from S3" which is specific to mysql on AWS does not show up after it is issued.

I've reproduced this with only pymysql(see below) which the ansible module uses and I get the same result.  I do not see any errors on the database, and the rest of the grants show up as expected.

- PyMySQL 1.0.2
- CPython 3.9.7
- docker: python:3.9.7-slim-buster

If anyone can provide a fix/shed some light/alternatives please let me know otherwise I'll keep digging.

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database 
connection = pymysql.connect(host='some_aurora_mysql_5.7_host',
                             user='some_user',
                             password='redacted',
                             database='redacted',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                                 ssl = {
                                    'ssl': {
                                        'activate': True
                                        }
                                    }
                             )
with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "GRANT SELECT,LOAD FROM S3 ON `some_table`.* TO 'some_user'@'%' "
        cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "show grants for some_user"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the LOAD FROM S3 is on the whole database server/cluster, not on individual databases.

So:
`GRANT LOAD FROM S3 ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'%'` works fine.